# Using the SwiftUI PreviewProvider to Display an Array

Tags: arrays, json, swiftui

Thanks to some help here I got this mostly working, but I'm not sure what the correct syntax is for how I can get SwiftUI's PreviewProvider to display the contents of my array "myDataModels".

Here is what I have:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Overview: View {
    var myDataModels: [MyDataModel]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(myDataModels) { model in
                Section(header: Text("\(model.firstName) \(model.lastName)")) {

                    ForEach(model.cities, id: \.name) { (city: City) in

                        Section(header: Text(city.name).fontWeight(.bold)) {

                            ForEach(city.towns, id: \.name) { town in
                                Text(town.name)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which compiles fine, but I'm not sure what the correct means of referencing myDataModels is for the PreviewProvider call just below the above block. Here is what I have there currently.

```
struct Overview_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Overview(myDataModels: userData[0])
    }
}
```

userData is a reference to the JSON file. But I get the error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'MyDataModel' to expected argument type '[MyDataModel]'
```

Any help us most appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you pass `userData` instead of `userData[0]` in your preview provider?

Comment: The error message was telling you what was wrong, you were passing a single object while your component was expecting an array.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've defined userData somewhere, you can just do

```
Overview(myDataModels: userData)
```

Or if you want to just send the one specific item:

```
Overview(myDataModels: [userData[0]])
```

If this doesn't work, please post your definition of userData.